# get opcode of instruction in capstone python

Tags: python, capstone

I understand that the opcodes are provided by myself to capstone for disassembly, but I would like to know what opcode was disassembled to get the provided instruction. Unfortunately, I couldn't find what key of `capstone.CsInsn` is called to get the opcode.

I tried the following keys, but neither of them is opcode:

```
for i in md.disasm(data, dataLength):
    print(i.mnemonic, i.address, i.op_str, i.operands, i.id, i.regs_read, i.regs_write, i.groups, type(i))

# returned values: ('fcmovnu', 512, 'st(0), st(2)', [<capstone.x86.X86Op object at 0x000001911AB019C0>, <capstone.x86.X86Op object at 0x000001911AB01E40>], 89, [], [31], [137, 169], <class 'capstone.CsInsn'>)
```

I just would like to know that `\xdb` opcode were disassembled to above assembly instructions.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can use `i.bytes`, so in your case you might use something like `i.bytes[0] == 0xdb`